# How to add parameters to redirect_uri in WebApi Oauth Owin authentication process?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm creating a webapi project with oauth bearer token authenthication and external login providers (google, twitter, facebook etc.). I started with the basic VS 2013 template and got everything to work fine!

However, after a user successfully logs is, the owin infrastructure creates a redirect with the folllowing structure:

```
http://some.url/#access_token=<the access token>&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600
```

In my server code I want to add an additional parameter to this redirect because in the registration process of my app, a new user needs to first confirm and accept the usage license before he/she is registered as a user. Therefore I want to add the parameter "requiresConfirmation=true" to the redirect. However, I've no clue about how to do this. I tried setting AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.RedirectUri of the AuthenticationManager but this doesn't seem to have any affect.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not check in the database when the user is authenticated after coming back from the external login request? Oh and to give you a tip: I not sure how you did it now, but I found it hard to capture the access_token, especially when you would like mobile devices to work with your api. It's a lot of work, but it works: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Comment: I only want the user in my data base _after_ he/she confirmed. Therefore I can't use the database for this. I started with the link you provided, but eventually ended-up with using the VS 2015 webapi template, which I found much more straight-forward to use. (I see now that I incorrectly mentioned that I was using the 2013 template, although I don't know the differences)

Comment: Well bit off-topic, but the problem I had with the template was: What if I already have an access token from facebook, that I got from the android app it self? Anyway if it works then ur OK.
To get back at your question, when returning from external login, you need the access token in your application anyway, because you need to use the token to validate the correct user. If there is no user yet that is assocoiated to that external account, then you know you have to ask for license agreement. Perhaps a better solution is to agree before registering.

Answer (score 1):

It should be relatively easy with the `AuthorizationEndpointResponse` notification:

**In your custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation, simply override `AuthorizationEndpointResponse` to extract your extra parameter from the ambient response grant, which is created when you call `IOwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity)`**.
You can then add a custom `requiresConfirmation` parameter to `AdditionalResponseParameters`: it will be automatically added to the callback URL (i.e in the fragment when using the implicit flow):

```
public override Task AuthorizationEndpointResponse(OAuthAuthorizationEndpointResponseContext context) {
    var requiresConfirmation = bool.Parse(context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Properties.Dictionary["requiresConfirmation"]);
    if (requiresConfirmation) {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("requiresConfirmation", true);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

**In your code calling `SignIn`, determine whether the user is registered or not and add `requiresConfirmation` to the `AuthenticationProperties` container:**

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
properties.Dictionary.Add("requiresConfirmation", "true"/"false");

context.Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
```

Feel free to ping me if you need more details.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot. I already figured out myself the use of AdditionalResponseParameters in the member AuthorizationEndpointResponse of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. The use of properties when calling SignIn was the missing part for me. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate if you still need help.