# Add extra parameters to .net Web API response after successful external provider authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am designing an .NET 4.6 SPA (single page application). I would like to return additional parameters after the user is authenticated.

in ApplicationOAuthProvider, I have the following code to return the additional parameters:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
       context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(Participant user, IEnumerable<string> roles)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "userName", user.UserName },
        { "fullName", user.FullName },
        { "userRoles", string.Join(",",roles) }
    };
    return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
}
```

This works well when returning JSON in reponse to a post to /Token, however, I am having trouble with the ExternalLogin Action - which uses the default AccountController template automatically generated when creating a .NET 4.6 SPA, but using the modified ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties function defined above.

```
bool hasRegistered = user != null;

if (hasRegistered)
{
    Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

     ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user, await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id));
    Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
}
...
return Ok();
```

I thought this would add additional parameters to the fragment after the redirect_uri#, but I am getting 3 parameters only (access_token, expires_in & token_type).

how do I add extra parameters to the fragment (or otherwise obtain the extra data in the browser window) after successful external authentication? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [answer in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833499/how-to-add-parameters-to-redirect-uri-in-webapi-oauth-owin-authentication-proces#30878672)

final code looked like:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    ...
    public override Task AuthorizationEndpointResponse(OAuthAuthorizationEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        var props = context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Properties.Dictionary;
        foreach (var k in props.Keys)
        {
            if (k[0] != '.' && !string.Equals(k,"client_id",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(k, props[k]);
            }
        }
        return base.AuthorizationEndpointResponse(context);
    }
```

The entire [project is up on GitHub](https://github.com/mcshaz/SimManager/tree/master/SM.Web)